# How to set an external editor in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode

All the posts I have found suggest going to the "file types" sub-section under XCode preferences and adding an external editor for a specific file type. However this options does not seem to be there on XCode 4.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *looks* like it just goes through LaunchServices, so... whatever you'd get by opening it using Finder by default.

Comment: To be specific. Open Finder and navigate to any .m file. Them press CMD-I to open the info window and change the default app to be MacVIM ( or other ) then select to change all files on the system to take this property. Do the same with .h files. Now within X-Code the external editor menu is no longer greyed out and will open MacVim when you click on it.

Comment: I really wish I could make open in external editor the default when clicking or double clicking in XCode. Then life would be amazing.

Comment: "Open in External Editor" is bindable, so I bound it to cmd+control+L.  Makes it fairly easy to the current file into my external editor without any clicks required.

Comment: There is a Xcode plugin in https://github.com/orta/OROpenInAppCode that can be easily changed to open your favorite editor, this one opens AppCode and can be installed via Alcatraz.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, finder chooses Xcode as the editor when opening .m files, what he meant is the option to open in external editor from INSIDE Xcode.  By your logic, it would use Xcode as external editor

Comment: @mksw use Finder to change your default if Xcode is the default on your system

Answer (score 0):

I had a look around and I couldn't figure it out. I notice that right-clicking on a source file, there is a greyed out option for "open in external editor." I couldn't figure out how to  get that working at a glance.

A reasonable workaround would be to right-click on the source file you want to edit, click "Reveal in Finder," and then edit the file in the editor of your choice. The changes will be automatically updated in Xcode. I think you'll lose any undo/redo history you may have had for that file in Xcode though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the editor you want is the default editor for the file type(cpp/h/lua ..).
step: first time you 'show in finder', then open the file with 'open as', then choose the editor you want, make sure you choose the 'always open it'. then every is ok now.

Comment: I think you missed a word: "you have to make *sure*..."

Comment: @ChrisLeyva or he might've meant "...  you want as the default...". He get's the point across though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you need to change the default setting for the file type in Finder. The best way to do that is to right-click any similar file in Finder. Select Get Info from the pop-up menu. Then look down the list for the "Open with" drop-down option. Select your chosen editor and then below the words "Use this option to open all documents like this one" click on "Change All..."

Then it will change the default for all your applications.