# How can we find the "file types" tab in XCode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, preferences

I am looking for the "file types" tab from Preferences in XCode 4.5 but I could not find it.

How can I get this tab?

Comment: are you talking about your Xcode project's document types?

Comment: I need to switch to the File Types tab, and find the text.html settings under the file/text group to choose HTML File as the preferred editor.But cann't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for your Xcode project document types (i.e. what kinds of documents your app will open), they can be found in your Project's Info pane.  It looks like this:

[image: Set Document Types for your Project]

Now, if you want to open files with a non-standard (for Macintosh) extension into Xcode (e.g. files that end with the name "`.zinnuree`"), or have another IDE besides Xcode open your source files, you can do a "Get Info" on those files and then specify the app you want to use to open those files.  More information can be found in [this closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223132/how-to-set-an-external-editor-in-x-code-4-2).

[image: Change Helper App]

Comment: I need "File Types" option which we found previous Xcode from Preferences menu.In Xcode 4.5 where i can find this option?