# Xcode environment — shortcuts and indentation utilities

Tags: xcode, sublimetext, utility

(Not sure if the question belongs here, so apologies are in order)

I am heavy on sublime text and I often find Xcode to be lacking with some of the text/data processing stuff. I might have more than one question here —

1. 'Command + /' comments code but there is no indentation. Are the any tools or utilities out there that could help me with this?
2. 'Command + C' and 'Command + X' copy and cut lines in sublime text when there is no text selected. Is this possible in Xcode?

Moving on, is there a set of plugins or utilities for Xcode that could make it a bit more like sublime text? I understand that I need to get along with Xcode and I have, but there are somethings that Xcode doesn't do well and I am wondering if there are ways to accommodate that.

Comment: Have you seen these [shortcut sheets](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html), they might help?

Comment: Hey, thanks. But that's not what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ST as an external editor for XCode?

How to set it up is here: 
[How to set an external editor in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223132/how-to-set-an-external-editor-in-x-code-4-2)

Then you could open your files in ST and edit there getting all the features of ST natively.

If you have already tried this and it wasn't a happy experience sorry for wasting your time.